# Call controller method and get data back on client

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, json

I want to call a server-side controller method which returns a string, which eventually will be JSON, then once I have the data back on the client I can inject it into part of the view for the user to see.

This is my current setup:

Controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def name
    name = "Sean"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {render json: name }
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
  resources :home do 
    collection do
      get 'name'
    end
  end
```

AJAX Call:

```
window.callAPI = () ->
  $.ajax
    type: "GET"
    url: "/home/name"
    success: (data) ->
      console.log data
    error: (error) ->
      console.log error
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Started GET "/home/name" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-22 13:28:59 -0700
Processing by HomeController#name as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template home/name, application/name with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/sylanz/Documents/NimbusCC/app/views"
):
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:10:in `name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Ajax call should be (notice the `dataType` option included):

```
$.ajax
  type: "GET"
  url: "/home/name"
  dataType: "json" #Added
  success: (data) ->
    console.log data
```

Comment: This got rid of the error that was occurring.  However, my `console.log(data)` is not firing.  EDIT: I just added an error call back and am getting back what I was expecting. The status code is 200 which should mean everything worked as planned, so why is it coming back in the error call back and not success?

Comment: @SeanCallahan the response may be invalid JSON.

Comment: Yeah, your string won't render as json. Try `name = {"name": "Sean"}`

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling `/home/name.json` - as the error says, otherwise Rails doesn't know you want a JSON response, and chooses HTML as the default one. And you don't have a HTML template.

In fact, if this action is a purely API endpoint, leave out the `format.html` clause altogether.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) shortcut available in jQuery. In this case it's a drop-in replacement for `ajax` with the part you're missing in your request, as documented by others: `dataType: "json"`.

How could you have figured that out? Notice in your logs:

```
:formats=>[:html]
```